# How to stop Inno-Setup installer if a certain date was expired?

Tags: inno-setup

Please let me know how to check the current date during the installation.

I have to embed a certain date in the installer script, and then notify the user and stop the installation process if current date (which is taken from Windows host) is bigger than hard-coded (embedded) date

Thank you

Comment: Note that if this is for a trialware thing, this is easily defeated.  You should have protection in the application itself instead.

Comment: Having a date check is perfectly valid. The difference between software with a check (thats easy to beat) and one without anything is vastly greater than software with a check that's difficult to beat and one thats easy to beat.

Answer (score 5):

An alternative solution using Inno's built-in date routine *GetDateTimeString*.

```
[Code] 

const MY_EXPIRY_DATE_STR = '20131112'; //Date format: yyyymmdd

function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
begin
  //If current date exceeds MY_EXPIRY_DATE_STR then return false and exit Installer.
  result := CompareStr(GetDateTimeString('yyyymmdd', #0,#0), MY_EXPIRY_DATE_STR) <= 0;

  if not result then
    MsgBox('This Software is freshware and the best-before date has been exceeded. The Program will not install.', mbError, MB_OK);
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to get the system date/time using the windows API, for example using the [GetLocalTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724338%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function and compare that to your hard coded date somewhere in your installer, for example during initialization, as I did in this example for you:

{lang:pascal}

```
[Code]
type
  TSystemTime = record
    wYear: Word;
    wMonth: Word;
    wDayOfWeek: Word;
    wDay: Word;
    wHour: Word;
    wMinute: Word;
    wSecond: Word;
    wMilliseconds: Word;
  end;

procedure GetLocalTime(var lpSystemTime: TSystemTime);  external 'GetLocalTime@kernel32.dll';

function DateToInt(ATime: TSystemTime): Cardinal;
begin
  //Converts dates to a integer with the format YYYYMMDD, 
  //which is easy to understand and directly comparable
  Result := ATime.wYear * 10000 + aTime.wMonth * 100 + aTime.wDay;
end;


function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
var
  LocTime: TSystemTime;
begin
  GetLocalTime(LocTime);
  if DateToInt(LocTime) > 20121001 then //(10/1/2012)
  begin
    Result := False;
    MsgBox('Now it''s forbidden to install this program', mbError, MB_OK);
  end
  else
  begin
    Result := True;
  end;
end;
```